# How do I toggle video mute in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Pretty Please...

I have one script running that mutes a video targeting an iframe, but it uses two buttons, and I want to to use one button that toggles.  What I want is a single button that toggles the muted sound state targeting an iframe.

This example doesn't use an iframe, because I couldn't figure out how to use it in jsfiddle, but the button can be changed from 
onclick="disableMute()       to
onclick="glu.disableMute()
to get it to work

[Example 1 Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zjfaqc1p/)

Javascript

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function enableMute() { 
    vid.muted = true;
} 

function disableMute() { 
    vid.muted = false;
}
```

html

```
<input type="image" src="http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeoff_orig.png" onclick="enableMute()" style="padding-top: 3px;">
<input type="image" src="http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeon_orig.png" onclick="disableMute()" style="padding-top: 3px;">
```

The next example uses JQuery to toggle mute with one button, but I can not figure out how to get it to target an iframe.

[Example 2 Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kar2nz/jhnp5Lur/)

Javascript

```
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$("video").prop('muted', true);

$(".mute-video").click(function () {
    if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
        $("video").prop('muted', false);
        $(this).addClass('unmute-video');

    } else {
        $("video").prop('muted', true);
        $(this).removeClass('unmute-video');
    }
    console.log($("video").prop('muted'))
});
});//]]>
```

css

```
body {
background-color:#000000
}
.mute-video {
background:url(http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeon_orig.png) no-repeat center;
    border:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.unmute-video {
    background:url(http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeoff_orig.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

html

```
<video autoplay controls height="352" width="640">
<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video><br>
<button class="mute-video"></button>
```

I hope this all makes sense.  I am struggling with this javascript thing, so please be patient with me.  I have tried the other similar questions here, but I can not get them to work, or are not exactly what I needed.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In first example you can mute/unmute using same button by following code :

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function muteUnmute() { 
    vid.muted = !vid.muted;
    if(!vid.muted){     document.getElementById("muteBtn").src="http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeon_orig.png";
    }else{
document.getElementById("muteBtn").src="http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeoff_orig.png";
    
    }

}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" autoplay controls height="352" width="640">
<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<br>
<input type="image" id="muteBtn" src="http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeon_orig.png" onclick="muteUnmute()" style="padding-top: 3px;">
```

Above code will work as toggle for mute.

> If you are using `<iframe>` :

Consider below iframe for example :

```
<iframe id="myVideo" src="your video url" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can use below function on your button click to toggle video volume between mute/unmute:

```
function muteUnmute(){
    var myVideo =  iframe.getElementById('myVideo'); 
    if(myVideo.isMuted()){
        myVideo.unMute();
    }else{
        myVideo.mute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your <iframe> code. I will try to come with something

Comment: Thanks again.  Thing is, there are two documents involved for many reasons.  here is the example of the iframe document.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am still not able to get it to work.  Lets see if I can get really specific.  There are reasons I am loading each video into its own document, and then loading those documents into an iframe from a list.

First, for the iframe document.


    <input type="image" onclick="glu.enableMute()"src="http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeoff_orig.png">
    <input type="image" onclick="glu.disableMute()" src="http://kar2nz.weebly.com/uploads/8/9/2/8/89280494/volumeon_orig.png"><br>
    <iframe width="340" height="200" name="glu" src="video.html">

Comment: Then the video document, which there are many of.

    <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" autoplay controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

    <script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

    function enableMute() { 
    vid.muted = true;
    } 

    function disableMute() { 
    vid.muted = false;
    } 
    </script>